# Subscribe to Subject didn't assign value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have service with getter and setter:

```
// Service
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class MyService {
  public currentUser: any = new Subject();

  ... there is a function where I call setCurrent and assign value

  set setCurrent(data: any) {
    this.currentUser.next(data);
    this._localStorage.set('user', JSON.stringify(data))
  }

  get setCurrent() {
    return this._localStorage.get('user');
  }
}
```

In my component I subscribed to `currentUser`:

```
// Component


  public user: User;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
  ) {
    this.authService.currentUser.subscribe(nextData => {
      this.user = nextData;
      console.log(nextData) // Expected value, it's here
      console.log(this.user) // Undefined
    })
  }
```

Why it's return needed and expected value, but didn't assign it to component variable?

Comment: If it's an object you could try to use Object.assign or `deepClone` from lodash

Answer (score 0):

When do you set `setCurrent`? If you do it before your subscription, you won't get the current value. You can try changing it to a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a `Subject`.